# In an array of strings how to sort the array on part of the strings

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I was beginning to write a bubble sort for this when I thought maybe there is a way to use a function with array.sort() that does the job ?

Here is a (hopefully) clear example of what I have to sort : (file names list)

```
var array = ['impression_page_1_12_juin','impression_page_1_13_juin','impression_page_2_12_juin','impression_page_2_13_juin']
```

As you can see there are 2 'page1' on 2 different dates, only characters 19 and 20 in each string are different. I'd like to sort on those 2 characters.

Can Javascript do that straightforward or should I return to my substrings and bubble sort method ?

Comment: characters 17, 19, and 20 are different in each string.

Comment: You're right... but I wanted to group the 'date' part in the list... page numbers are already sorted. Thanks for nailing it ;-)

Comment: this isn't a google-apps-script question ...

Comment: @Edo, sorry, my question was tagged javascript *and* GAS, I don't think this is really off topic, do you ?

Comment: it's not a big deal but I don't get how this question can be related to GAS ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `sort` method with a function for the comparison:

```
array.sort(function(x,y){
  var xp = x.substr(18, 2);
  var yp = y.substr(18, 2);
  return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: jeee, that's fast ! and when I see it I find it cristal clear ;-) thanks

Comment: I adjusted this for my use, and while it works for a small array (<10 entries), it doesn't for a larger array (70-100 entries), and I don't quite understand why. Is there something I can adjust for it to work for a larger array?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can pass a function to array.sort that compares the two strings according to whatever criteria you're interested in. See [How to sort array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185441/how-to-sort-array-in-javascript?rq=1)

You will have to be careful with strings vs. numbers: `'1_12' < '1_2'` is `True`, for instance. If you need to compare them as numbers, you could split the strings, do parseInt on each part, and implement a pairwise comparison.