# How to sort an array of string objects by the first word A then B in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects like the one below:

[image]

How can I order them by first word then the second. Like:

```
-Bulb: Vari-Fair
-Octopus: Agile
-Octopus: Energy Go


0: {id: 6, value: "Octopus: Agile"}
1: {id: 19, value: "EDF: EDF Economy 10 (SV)"}
2: {id: 20, value: "Octopus: Energy Go"}
3: {id: 21, value: "Igloo: Pioneer"}
4: {id: 22, value: "Scottish Power: Smart Green EV"}
5: {id: 23, value: "OVO: EV Everywhere"}
6: {id: 24, value: "E.ON: Fix and Drive"}
7: {id: 25, value: "Tonik: Charge EV"}
8: {id: 26, value: "Engie: EV Home"}
9: {id: 27, value: "Good Energy: EV Tariff"}
10: {id: 28, value: "Ecotricity: Fully Charged"}
11: {id: 29, value: "Bulb: Vari-Fair"}
12: {id: 30, value: "Green Energy UK: TIDE"}
13: {id: 32, value: "Our Power: Economy 10"}
```

Comment: what you tried to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175268/javascript-sort-function-sort-by-first-then-by-second

Comment: @Sergey this is not related since the problem is all the the object is one string.

Comment: you may split the strings in the parts and then compare in the sort

Comment: [In an array of strings how to sort the array on part of the strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016795/in-an-array-of-strings-how-to-sort-the-array-on-part-of-the-strings)

Comment: Have you tried writing any code? Any attempt?

Comment: @HS an example would be great :)

Comment: @undefined sorry i know that stackoverflow isn't for that, but didn't know where to start

Comment: let me give some example. @AnXD

Comment: @AnXD if it's a problem to split the strings then you'd better learn some basics of JavaScript strings first.

Comment: @AnXD No problem. Please post the actual code instead of an image of it.

Comment: @Sergey thank you for your advice man, but didn't came here for that. Thanks!

Comment: @undefined done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the value by ': ' and compare first and second:

```
const toSort = [
    {id: 6, value: "Octopus: Agile"},
    {id: 19, value: "EDF: EDF Economy 10 (SV)"},
    {id: 20, value: "Octopus: Energy Go"},
    {id: 21, value: "Igloo: Pioneer"},
    {id: 22, value: "Scottish Power: Smart Green EV"},
    {id: 23, value: "OVO: EV Everywhere"},
    {id: 24, value: "E.ON: Fix and Drive"},
    {id: 25, value: "Tonik: Charge EV"},
    {id: 26, value: "Engie: EV Home"},
    {id: 27, value: "Good Energy: EV Tariff"},
    {id: 28, value: "Ecotricity: Fully Charged"},
    {id: 29, value: "Bulb: Vari-Fair"},
    {id: 30, value: "Green Energy UK: TIDE"},
    {id: 32, value: "Our Power: Economy 10"}
]
const sorted = toSort.sort((a,b) => {
    const f = a.value.split(': ');
    const s = b.value.split(': ');
    if(f[0] > s[0])
        return 1;
    if(f[0] < s[0])
        return -1;
    if(f[1] > s[1])
        return 1;
    return -1;
});
console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follow:

```js
var arr = [
{id: 6, value: "Octopus: Agile"},
{id: 19, value: "EDF: EDF Economy 10 (SV)"},
{id: 20, value: "Octopus: Energy Go"},
{id: 21, value: "Igloo: Pioneer"},
{id: 22, value: "Scottish Power: Smart Green EV"},
{id: 23, value: "OVO: EV Everywhere"},
{id: 24, value: "E.ON: Fix and Drive"},
{id: 25, value: "Tonik: Charge EV"},
{id: 26, value: "Engie: EV Home"},
{id: 27, value: "Good Energy: EV Tariff"},
{id: 28, value: "Ecotricity: Fully Charged"},
{id: 29, value: "Bulb: Vari-Fair"},
{id: 30, value: "Green Energy UK: TIDE"},
{id: 32, value: "Our Power: Economy 10"}
];
var result = arr.sort((a,b)=>a.value.localeCompare(b.value)); //utf8 support
console.log(result);
```